# In bash, how do I delete child directories older than the date that another directory was created?

Tags: bash, directory, delete

I can use the following command to delete child directories in a particular directory older than x number of days

```
find /path/to/base/dir/* -type d -ctime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

but how would I delete child directories that were older than the date when another dirctory was created?  I know I can get the date using

```
$ ls -l /var/www/cfs-web/current
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser mygroup 41 Feb 22 23:19 /path/to/main/dir
```

but I’m not sure how to combine this with the above.

Comment: `ctime` is not _creation time_. It's _inode change time_, i.e. the time that attributes or metadata were changed for the file/directory

Answer (score 1):

> how would I delete child directories that were older than the date when another dirctory was created?

There is unlikely to be a created date or birth date attribute for files/directories.

If the last modified time will suffice, you can simply change `ctime +10` to `! -newer reference` where 'reference' is the directory whose modification time you want to use as a reference.

If your system does store birth date file attributes, you could use `! -newerBB reference`.